# Entrypoint file not being found for Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Trying to run this Docker Compose file and running into an issue during the Dockerfile build stage where if I build a test of the Dockerfile outside of the compose file it seems to work, but when I try it live, it always fails with the error:

```
Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "./entrypoint.sh": stat ./entrypoint.sh: no such file or directory: unknown
```

**Docker File:**

```
FROM debian:bullseye

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y cmake build-essential curl git

RUN echo "deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ bullseye main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspi.list
RUN curl "https://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/raspberrypi.gpg.key" | apt-key add -

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libcamera-dev libjpeg-dev libgphoto2-dev

RUN git clone https://github.com/ArduCAM/mjpg-streamer.git /src
WORKDIR /src/mjpg-streamer-experimental

RUN sed -i "/input_libcamera/p;/input_/d;/output_http/p;/output_/d" CMakeLists.txt
RUN make && make install

COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
ENV INPUT_FLAGS "-r 1640x1232 -f 10"
ENV OUTPUT_FLAGS "-w ./www"
RUN chmod +x entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
```

**Docker Compose File: **

```
version: "3"

services:
  mjpg-streamer:
    build:
      context: ./mjpg-streamer
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
    privileged: true
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      - INPUT_FLAGS=-r 1640x1232 -f 10
      - OUTPUT_FLAGS=-w ./www
    volumes:
      - /run/udev:/run/udev:ro
      - /opt/Octoprint/mjpg-streamer:/mjpg-streamer

  octoprint:
    image: octoprint/octoprint:latest
    restart: always
    privileged: true
    ports:
      - 9003:80
    devices:
      - /dev/ttyUSB0:/dev/ttyUSB0
    volumes:
      - /opt/Octoprint/data/octoprint:/octoprint
      - /proc/cpuinfo:/proc/cpuinfo:ro
      - /usr/bin/vcgencmd:/usr/bin/vcgencmd:ro
      - /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libvcos.so.0:/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libvcos.so.0:ro
      - /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libvchiq_arm.so.0:/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libvchiq_arm.so.0:ro
```

These docker files are based on this repo: [octoprint-libcamera](https://github.com/ruiqimao/octoprint-libcamera)

I have made several alterations to fit my own environment, and the Octoprint side of the docker-compose works without issue. It all seems to be tied to the Entrypoint.sh file

I've wracked my brain around this for a week now. As far as I can guess, the entrypoint file isn't being properly sent to the container but uncertain why. A second (or several) pair of eyes would be appreciated.

I made several alterations to the entrypoint location in futile attempts to resolve the issue.

Attempt 1:

```
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
ENV INPUT_FLAGS "-r 1640x1232 -f 10"
ENV OUTPUT_FLAGS "-w ./www"
RUN chmod +x entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["./mjpg-streamer/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Attempt 2:

```
COPY /entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
ENV INPUT_FLAGS "-r 1640x1232 -f 10"
ENV OUTPUT_FLAGS "-w ./www"
RUN chmod +x entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
```

Attempt 3:

```
COPY /entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
ENV INPUT_FLAGS "-r 1640x1232 -f 10"
ENV OUTPUT_FLAGS "-w ./www"
RUN chmod +x entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["./mjpg-streamer/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Attempt 4:

```
COPY entrypoint.sh entrypoint.sh
ENV INPUT_FLAGS "-r 1640x1232 -f 10"
ENV OUTPUT_FLAGS "-w ./www"
RUN chmod +x entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
```

Attempt 5:

```
COPY ./mjpg-streamer/entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
ENV INPUT_FLAGS "-r 1640x1232 -f 10"
ENV OUTPUT_FLAGS "-w ./www"
RUN chmod +x entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
```

Comment: In all but attempt 4, you're copying `entrypoint.sh` into the root directory of the image, but the `ENTRYPOINT` line is trying to run it out of the current directory or somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using `CMD ["./entrypoint.sh"]` instead (or alternatively `ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "-c", "./entrypoint.sh"]`).

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21564990/22441360) has a more in-depth description about the difference between the two.

For example:

```
COPY entrypoint.sh .
ENV INPUT_FLAGS=-r 1640x1232 -f 10
ENV OUTPUT_FLAGS=-w ./www
RUN chmod +x entrypoint.sh
CMD ["./entrypoint.sh"]
```

Comment: Thank you. This answer combined with running the docker command 
`docker compose up --build`
seems to have got it working! Thanks again!

Comment: (`CMD` is probably better than `ENTRYPOINT`; it's easier to override with `docker run` and more compatible with using `ENTRYPOINT` for a startup-time wrapper script.  For this command you don't need the `sh -c` wrapper, and if you do need it, Docker will insert it for you if you use the non-JSON-array shell form of `CMD`.)